# Resetear un setTimeout

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de hacer una cuenta regresiva de 60s y cuando presiono el botón que se reinicie la cuenta. Lo logré pero a medias porque cuando presiono tiene un retardo de un segundo, no logro eliminar ese segundo de más que me queda.

Les dejo el código:

```js
let inicio = 60,
               divSegundos = document.querySelector('#segundos'),
               divContador = document.querySelector('#div-contador'),
               boton = document.querySelector('#boton');

          (function countdown() {
               var count = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);

               if (inicio == 0) {
                    divSegundos.innerText = '0' + inicio;
                    clearTimeout(count);
               } else {
                    if (inicio < 10) {
                         divSegundos.innerText = '0' + inicio;
                    } else {
                         divSegundos.innerText = inicio;
                    }
               }
               inicio--;

               function resetCountdown() {
                    inicio = 60;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                         clearInterval(countdown);
                    });
               }

               boton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    resetCountdown();
               });
          })();
```

```html
<div id="div-contador">
          <div id="minutos">00</div>
          <span>:</span>
          <div id="segundos"></div>
     </div>
     <br>
     <button id="boton">Presionar</button>
```

Si hay alguna ayuda se agradece :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta ejecutar la primera vez manualmente para ahorrar ese tiempo

```js
let inicio = 60,
     divSegundos = document.querySelector('#segundos'),
     divContador = document.querySelector('#div-contador'),
     boton = document.querySelector('#boton');

(function() {
     var interval;
     
     function countdown(){
       if (inicio == 0) {
            divSegundos.innerText = '0' + inicio;
       } else {
            if (inicio < 10) {
                 divSegundos.innerText = '0' + inicio;
            } else {
                 divSegundos.innerText = inicio;
            }
       }
       inicio--;
     }
     
     function init(){
        interval = setInterval(countdown, 1000)
     }

     function resetCountdown() {
        inicio = 60;
        clearInterval(interval);
        countdown(); // ejecutar primera vez manual, para evitar esperar 1 seg
        init();
     }

     boton.addEventListener('click', () => {
          resetCountdown();
     });
     
     init()
})();
```

```html
<div id="div-contador">
          <div id="minutos">00</div>
          <span>:</span>
          <div id="segundos"></div>
     </div>
     <br>
     <button id="boton">Presionar</button>
```

Comment: Funciona, gracias! Ahora tengo el problema del retardo de un segundo cuando actualizo :/

Comment: Genial! Si te ayudo, te pido marques la respuesta como aceptada, gracias